# How would I add properties to an entity using a method instead of hard coding it (using Entity Framework)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, entity

I am using Entity Framework to help store some entities I have coded in C# to create a simple web application. I want to know how to add a property (field) to an entity without coding it into the entity class. Take my employee entity, for example:

```
public class Employee : Person
{
    public int OfficeID { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }

    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say I want the employee entity to also have a

```
string Certifications
```

property that describes the employees certifications. I could just write it below the line where I define the salary.

However, I need to be able to implement functionality so that a user can add a property using the web application, which means it can't just be hardcoded. What I'm imagining is that there is an "Add Property" button, and when the user clicks it, they have to:

- Select the entity to which they want to add the property (e.g. Employee entity)
- Write the name of the property as well as its type (e.g. Certifications, string)
- Write the value of this property (e.g. "Officially certified as an OK programmer")

I am new to all of this, so bear with me, but it's not intuitive to me that I could write a method that takes in user input for the entity, property name and type, and the value of the property, then add this to that entity to make it a property just like the other properties hardcoded in the entity class. I would really appreciate if anyone has any suggestions on how to go about persisting properties added at run time and linking them to the entity so they function just as if they were coded in the entity class like the original properties.

I have a method that allows the user to edit the value of one of the properties of the "Office" entity [(credit to Tom Dykstra's Entity Framework 6 tutorial at asp.net)](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application):

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditPost(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var officeToUpdate = db.Offices.Find(id);
    if (TryUpdateModel(officeToUpdate, "",
       new string[] { "Address", "BusinessName" }))
    {
        try
        {
           db.SaveChanges();

           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (DataException /* dex */)
        {
            //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }
    }
    return View(officeToUpdate);
}
```

However instead of simply editing the value of one of the properties, I am asking how to edit the entity so that a whole new property + value is added. I hope my post is clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how this is possible in the exact way that you describe it.

If I needed to have this sort of "extensible" entity requirement, where users can dynamically add new properties, I would create a couple of generic tables + entities for that exact purpose. And it would look something like this:

```
public class ExtraEntityProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}

public class ExtraEntityPropertyValue
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // PK
    public int ExtraEntityPropertyId { get; set; } // FK
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

...and this could be normalized a bit more, depending on how you would want to work with it.

The point here is that, this way, you deal purely in terms of data, something EF can do for you dynamically.  If users need to add new properties dynamically, then you add new rows to the ExtraEntityProperty table.  And if the users assign new values to those properties, then you add rows to the ExtraEntityPropertyValue.

Personally, I am not a big fan of these generic solutions, because you lose a lot of the type safety that you would otherwise get if you can statically pre-define your types and properties ahead of time.  But if you really need to be fully dynamic, then maybe you can take this idea and make it work for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to think about this. I think I understand what you're saying -- I'll try something similar to what you're describing, and see if there's anything else out there.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to using stack overflow. How do I do that? I don't see an accept answer button or anything (if that's what you're talking about). I also would upvote your answer but I don't have 15 reputation haha. Edit: Was it the tick button under the score? I just clicked that